# Floating panels with Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, panel

I am building a web application that is used to control a lot of other applications and also displays data from those applications.  I know that does not provide a lot of information but just think of it as a controller application.  Having the ability to display multiple panels would be very useful for the user so they can open a window for each server/application they want to view and control.  I like the look and abilities of jsPanel, but I want to compose the entire application with the current version of Angular.  Can I use jsPanel with Angular 7?   Is there another CSS library or js library or other technique that I can use with Angular to display multiple movable panels on the screen?
...or should

Comment: please add you code link